# Ionic Cordova ngx Translate always adds a white space at the beginning

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I am developing a multi language app with Ionic 4 and recently upgraded to Ionic 5 which doesn't make any difference to the behaviour of the plugin.

The texts are being translated and the plugin overall works fine but there is one thing that grinds my gears. the plugin always adds a white space infront of the text. I haven't any whitespaces in the html nor in the tranlsation .json...

`{{'Hello' | translate}}`
translates to " Hallo".

This happens on all platforms and with `ionic serve` in the browser (tried chrome and firefox, which is obsolete since I want to deploy on android and ios).

ionic info: 
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.0
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

plugin version:
 
      "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
      "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0"

I hope you have a guess what it could be. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the issue. The Compiler diesn't recognize the indent of the html row. 
`<div class="intro">{{'Hello'|translate}}</div>`
translates perfectly.
Otherwise

```
<div class="intro">
    {{'User.card.intro'|translate}}
</div>
```

doesn't. 
And this only works if the translated text is in a `<div>` inside `<ion-content>`

Comment: I have added <span> {{'string.to.translate' | translate}} </span> around and it works as well.